# QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget fails in debug mode

Tags: c++, qt, vtk, qvtkwidget

My C++  program in Visual call QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget and works fine in Release mode. However, when I change to Debug mode it fails to build which seems yo be related to Qt5Core. Note that Qt5Core.dll exist in my Qt/bin. I also build VTK library in both release and debug mode whish seems to work fine for other example in Debug mode. Below is the exception that VS through. I also pasted the last line of code where  VS crash. any feedback will help. Thanks  in advance :

ERROR:
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFCD52E2D28 (Qt5Core.dll) in ACOUPRO.exe: Fatal program exit requested..

CODE:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
// set up UI
ui->setupUi(this);
QRect rec = QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry();
ui->graphicsView->setGeometry(0, 0, rec.width(), rec.height() - 300);
ui->textBrowser->setGeometry(0, rec.height() - 300, rec.width(), rec.height());

container = new QWidget(ui->graphicsView);
qvtkWidget = new QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget(container);
....
}
```

Comment: How did you install Qt on your system?

Comment: @abderrazak-mejdi Seem we are having the same problem..! Did you find the solution?